# How can I prevent error in order to complete the loop?

Tags: r

I am trying to fit the best distribution for three variables which are gathered via .csv file. I tried to evaluate with provided distributions in r.
Then I will select the smallest one as a best fitted distribution. However, I cannot complete the loop because some errors can be occured when distributions are not able to be fitted for data.

for instance; beta distribution:

## Error in fitdistr(xx1[, k], distributions[i]) : 'start' must be a named list

So how can skip this error?

Here is the file to be uploaded : http://www.filedropper.com/samplest

Here is the code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)   

importeddata <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep=";",na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)

for(i in 1:tail(ncol(importeddata))){
  importeddata[,i] <- gsub(",", ".", importeddata[ , i])} 

xx1<- as.matrix(as.data.frame(lapply(importeddata, as.numeric)))

distributions <- c("beta", "cauchy", "chi-squared", "exponential", "f", "gamma", "geometric", "log-normal", "lognormal", "logistic", "negative binomial", "normal", "Poisson", "t", "weibull")


for(k in 1:ncol(xx1))
for(i in 1:length(distributions))
{
aa <- fitdistr(xx1[,k], distributions[i])$loglik
suppressMessages(aa)
print(aa)
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation. For some distributions you must supply starting values for numeric optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to skip some code when the error occurs you can use the `try()` function. Everything that is inside the function won't break the code when an error occurs.

In your example, just substitute:

`aa <- fitdistr(xx1[,k], distributions[i])$loglik`

for

`try({aa <- fitdistr(xx1[,k], distributions[i])$loglik})`